# How do I add active class to a current <a> without href?

Tags: jquery, location-href

I want to add an *active* class to the current `<a>` without `href`.
I have this language list:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a data-value="en">English</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-value="de">Deutsch</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-value="nl">Nederlands</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And this jquery:

```
a.click(function(event) {
    var url = location.href = "index.php?lang=" + $(this).attr("data-value");
location.href = url;    
});
```

I trying to add class *active* to `<a>` as the following:

```
a.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
```

But when i change language the page refresh and the .addClass doesn't work, so i tried to add class active based on URL (the url of pages is mysite.com/**index.php?lang=en**, mysite.com/**index.php?lang=de**, etc):

```
var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
$('a[href="' + href + '"]').addClass('current');
```

but even this doesn't work!
I assume that the problem is caused from `data-value`, so how can I add active class to the current  without href and add the class also after the refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the language from the current location and then use that to find the correct anchor:

```
var lang;

if (lang = location.href.match(/lang=([a-z]{2})/)) {
  $('[data-value=' + lang[1] + ']').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but doesn't work.. `select.click(function(event) {
 location.href = "index.php?lang=" + $(this).attr("data-value"); 
 var lang = location.href.match(/lang=([a-z]{2})/)[1];
 if (lang) {
   $('[data-value=' + lang + ']').addClass('active');
 }
});`

Comment: @Fuiba Eh no, the code in my answer should NOT run in the click handler, but on the page itself.